# Using android phone as wifi antenna on Ubuntu

Tags: usb, internet, android, sharing

When I tried to share my internet via usb cable (using it as wifi antenna) after 1 minute or 2 the conection fails and even if I disconnect and re-enable the usb-sharing, It will fail again now after just a couple of seconds, this happens with ubuntu 16.04.1 and 16.10 which I tried

Comment: Does it happen with other computers?

Comment: You mean you use your phone as a cable hotspot?

Comment: yes I happens with every machine I tried (3 laptops) I fact I mean cable hotspot